# Uploading a file from local to server through FTP using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, ftp

I would like to upload a file to server from my local. I have tried following code but it is giving some error. Please help me to resolve

```
<?php 
$server="115.120.147.261";
$ftp_user_name="root";
$ftp_user_pass="3424dd";
$dest="/home/root/web/Price-War/";
$source="/home/root/sample.txt";
$connection = ftp_connect($server);
if($connection)
{
echo "Connection Established";
}
$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, FTP_ASCII);

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);
?>
```

Its throwing following error.

```
Connection Established
PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): Could not create file. in /home/root/Desktop/upload.php on line 16
```

Comment: Check your folder permission if it is already set to 777?

Comment: I have given file permission . But still  I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you (or rather your script) does not have the required access rights to create a file. Check that the directory is owned by the user that executes the script. You may need to grant specific permissions for the *upload directory* (with regard to your script) using the `chmod` command.

A lot of people will tell you to use `chmod 777 directoryname` or `chmod 755 directoryname` to allow the script to create and edit files. However, this may pose a serious security issue because it allows all users to access and edit files in the directory.

Comment: The script only needs rights to read, but there must be rights for writing to the ftp server.

Comment: I have given file permission . But still  I am getting same error.

Comment: ftp_put() function will right /upload into server @doev

Answer (score 0):

> $dest="/home/root/web/Price-War/";

You need to set a filename.

> $dest="/home/root/web/Price-War/sample.txt"

Comment: But dest variable has to write file into that location. So I hope no need to specify file name.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Can you up load with a ftp-client to that destination?

Comment: I uploaded using filezilla.  I am able to upload to that destination

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I use the same code in my scripts and it works fine ... with the change of $dest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72824/discussion-between-doev-and-kathirvel-appusamy).

Answer (score 0):

Put this LOC above ftp_put().
You may have to assign the uploading mode to passive in order to upload a file.

```
ftp_pasv($connection, true);
```

Comment: Well OK, 3 things we want to figure out. 1. Your destination path, 2. File name as it is uploaded. 3. Where is your file come from? ($_FILES?)

Comment: Destination is $dest . Filename is sample.txt . Source of file is /home/root/

Comment: Are you able to reach sample.txt? Because it should saved at your web server's root directory. If you can't make sure, use file_exists($source) to check. If it returns false, that means source not found. If yes, see if FTP is accessible to read files from the root directory? If no, FTP didn't gained enough permission.

Comment: function is returning true. I don't think its something issue with permission because if it permission issue function will not return true. Correct me If I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with PHP and FTP, except I'm downloading not uploading. My local path needs to be the absolute path (full path) to the file, and my FTP path needs to be relative.. kinda like this:

```
$ftp_path = "/foldername/filename.txt";
$local_path = "C:\wamp\www\my_website\files\file_to_upload.txt"
```

Get your local path like this:

```
$path_to_root   = dirname(__FILE__);
$local_folder   = "\my_website\files\";
$local_full_path= $path_to_root.$local_folder."file_to_upload.txt";
```

I'm also using ftp_nb_get() rather than ftp_get() so I can run additional code while its downloading (such as checking file size of partially downloaded file). Have a look at my code here:

[PHP ftp_nb_get get local partial file size while downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964116/php-ftp-nb-get-get-local-partial-file-size-while-downloading)